# index is outside the bounds of the array vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Private Sub GetGeneralMemberInformation(Member As WebServices.MemberInfoService.Member)
        Try
            Dim error_msg As String = "The following Member is not Eligible to display the  data: {0} "
            SubscriberId = Member.SubscriberId
            If Member.Eligibility(0) Is Nothing Then
                Throw New Exception(String.Format(error_msg, SubscriberId))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I'm unable to check do null check on the Eligibility object .while checking itself i'm getting the error like index is outside the bounds of the array . Can any body suggest me how to do null check and i want display mu custom error message instead of that one and here eligibility  object don't have any data.

Comment: If IsDBNull(Member.Eligibility(0)) Then
                    Throw New Exception(String.Format(error_msg, SubscriberId))
                End If   I have tried this one also but no use same error.

Comment: `Member.Eligibility` could be empty

Comment: If 'Member.Eligibility' is something that has an index (array, list, whatever), then you should check to see if it contains anything first: `If Member.Eligibility.Count > 0 Then`. Otherwise, stop trying to access index 0 from an object that doesn't have an index and use Maximo's answer.

Comment: Thanks Franklin   If Member.Eligibility.Length = 0  Then
                    Throw New Exception(String.Format(error_msg, SubscriberId))
                End If

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, Eligibility may be empty. Since you clarified that Eligibility is a List(Of Object), I updated the code sample below to reflect that.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim member1 = New Member()
        member1.Eligibilities = New List(Of MemberEligibility)

        ' REMARKS: List is empty
        If member1.Eligibilities.Count > 0 Then
            If member1.Eligibilities(0) Is Nothing Then
                Console.WriteLine("First element is NULL")
            End If
        End If

        ' REMARKS: Add one element to list
        member1.Eligibilities.Add(New MemberEligibility())

        ' REMARKS: List contains one element        
        If member1.Eligibilities.Count > 0 Then
            If member1.Eligibilities(0) IsNot Nothing Then
                Console.WriteLine("First element is initialized")
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Member
    Private _eligibility As MemberEligibility
    Private _eligibilities As List(Of MemberEligibility)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Property Eligibility As MemberEligibility
        Get
            Return Me._eligibility
        End Get

        Set
            Me._eligibility = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Eligibilities As List(Of MemberEligibility)
        Get
            Return Me._eligibilities
        End Get

        Set
            Me._eligibilities = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class MemberEligibility
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ovOdAZ) showing the above code in action.

Comment: Member.Eligibility could be something but just with a count of 0

Comment: @the_lotus True but it is not clear from his code what Eligibility is, especially since the property name is singular I'd expect it to be an object; otherwise, it should be plural reflecting the fact that the member can have n number of eligibility items.

Comment: Here Member is object and Eligibility is list item .object within the object .

Comment: @harry Updated code sample reflecting usage of List (Of Object).